# How to calculate data from rows in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this one below:

```
datatime      in_out     
---------------------
08:00         IN
08:30         OUT
09:30         OUT
10:00         IN
10:30         OUT
```

Is there any chance, after a SQL server query to get something like this:

```
IN       OUT
---------------
08:00    08:30
NULL     09:30
10:00    10:30
```

I spent about 2 weeks to find a solution. I am a beginner. The single solution was with `min` and `max` but it did not help me.

Comment: The basic trick here is to join the table to itself, where the matching rule (ON condition) is the first OUT row that is after the IN row, or the first IN row that is before the OUT row. The trick is the NULL in your example: the exact code you need will depend on how you want to handle that (which is why this is just a comment). Tell us how to handle the nulls, and we can give you a complete answer.

Comment: I want to make another column for duration were to calculate in and out time with datediff. Its not important the null. If i have null on in or out column then null to duration column to. Here is an query for the first table. SELECT [UnitTS],
       case when RdrHead = 'A' THEN 'OUT' ELSE 'IN 'END as Reader
      ,[RdrName]
      ,[CrdName]
     
  FROM [Pontaj].[dbo].[History]
  where (UnitNr = '3' and RdrNr IN ('0','2','3') OR UnitNr = '4' and RdrNr IN('1','6')) 
and Type = 'A' and RdrHead in ('A','B') and Substring(unitts,1,8) = '20140108' and CrdName = ''

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? Also what is your actual table structure? Is it really just time or is there a date somewhere?

Comment: If you have IN, IN, OUT, OUT, then how do you assign the values?  Also, do you ever have `IN` with no matching `OUT`, or just `OUT` with no matching `IN`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will solve it using row_numbering:

```
with Ordered as (
    select *, rn = row_number() over (order by datatime)
    from Input
)
select
    [In] = o_in.datatime
,   [Out] = o_out.datatime
from Ordered o_out
 left join Ordered o_in
   on o_in.rn = o_out.rn - 1
  and o_in.in_out = 'IN'
where o_out.in_out = 'OUT'
```

Comment: WOW, John is this magic ? :) Its working. Thank you, have a nice day.

Comment: Note: If you get IN, IN in a row... this'll skip that row (should still be accurate calculated results, there will just be no row instead of a NULL row in the results)  Not that I have a solution to that yet, and if this works I won't bother looking.

Comment: I will make some test tomorrow and i will take a look to see if this will skip the row

Answer (score 0):

Guess I'm a bit slow to answer, but here's what I got using an inner query:

```
select
  (select top 1 
     IIF(a.in_out = b.in_out, null, datatime)
   from clk b 
   where a.datatime > b.datatime 
   order by b.datatime desc
  ) as [IN],
  a.datatime as [OUT]
from clk a
where a.in_out = 'OUT'
```

Note: doing it this way will "skip" the null rows either forwards or backwards depending on which way it's implemented...